# sbt incremental compilation not working in Java 11

Tags: java, scala, sbt, java-11

Having an issue currently that I discovered after migrating our Java/Scala project to OpenJDK 11.0.1. Before migration, we were able to incrementally compile with sbt by running the following commands:

```
> sbt
> compile
```

Afterwards, running compile again in the shell would incrementally compile and basically finish instantly since it was entirely compiled. However, after migrating, it recompiles the whole project after re-entering the sbt console and compiling. However, inc. compilation still works if I don't exit out of sbt. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

I am using sbt v0.13.17 and scala version 2.11.12. which according to [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html) are the minimum versions of Scala and sbt required for Java 11. Scala does say that they aren't officially compatible with Java 11 quite yet, but the outstanding bugs [here](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/139) don't have anything to do with SBT's incremental compiler

Comment: note that the sbt 0.13.x series is nearing EOL, you should strongly consider moving to sbt 1 (currently sbt 1.2.7)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Looks like there was [a bug introduced in SBT 0.13.17](http://github.com/sbt/zinc/pull/502). This was fixed in 0.13.18 so I just upgraded the versions and everything works perfectly